# Oracle SQL syntax error in Netbeans

Tags: java, sql, oracle, netbeans

I'm in the process of creating a trigger to allow me to automatically update the primary key when I insert a new record. This seems to be the preferential method according to Google.

However, when I'm running the following SQL code:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER rooms_insert
BEFORE INSERT ON "ROOMS"
FOR EACH ROW
    SELECT rooms_id_seq.nextval into :new.ID from dual;
```

The following error occurs:

```
Error code -1, SQL state 42X01: Syntax error: Encountered "OR" at line 1, column 8.
```

I'm not sure why I'm getting this error, and I've tried to Google it but I've had some trouble pinning this one down.

I'm using Netbeans to run the database alongside a Java application. I have the feeling I'm missing something obvious.

Any thoughts would be appreciated.

Thanks for reading :)

Comment: `CREATE OR REPLACE trigger rooms_insert...`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that it's just the syntax of Apache Derby.

I'm not entirely sure how to implement this as a trigger, but the following code creates a table with an auto-incrementing primary key:

```
CREATE TABLE ROOMS (ID INTEGER NOT NULL(START WITH 1, INCREMENT BY 1),
ROOMNAME VARCHAR(20), PRIMARY KEY (ID));
```

This is, as far as I can tell, the default RDBMS that Netbeans uses, which is what caught me off guard.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are missing the word "trigger" after the word "replace".

Comment: I've already tried that. I get the exact same error (probably should have mentioned).